# When is a moving test mass unbound from a black hole?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, black-holes, orbital-motion, escape-velocity

Imagine a small test mass $m$ with speed $v$ and distance $r$ from a Schwarzschild black hole of mass $M$. (The test mass is anywhere, but NOT on the horizon. Also, $m << M$.)

What condition on $v$ and $r$ must be valid so that the particle can escape to infinity?

In detail: what is the gravitational potential around a Schwarzschild black hole? Once it is known, the condition is simply that the kinetic energy be larger than the (negative) potential energy.

A message for all beginners: the gravitational potential around a Schwarzschild black hole is NOT a 1/r potential. It is more complicated than this.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I have tries to find an expression for the effective gravitational potential. But I am not sure that it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

let m2 = m (in your question)

1/2 m2v^2=Gm1m2*(1/R-1/infinite), R is your current distance from the center of gravity of the black hole.

R=r+Schwarzschild radius
If I am not wrong, then:

m2v^2=2Gm1m2/R

let Schwarzschild radius=x

v=root (2Gm1/(r+x))

Edit 1: +to answer your question, you need to understand that the universe doesn't care for whatever or however we label it.

Following the simplicity of the Newtonian model, for roughly everything in the universe, we use his "law" of gravity to work out the potential energies. Physicists chose that the gravitational potential energy of a system (or the object with lesser mass) is only 0 when it is at an infinite distance from the gravity source or the other mass. Now, this follows directly from the 1/r^2 term, because if gravitational force exists, we can show by calculus (or maths if you do not know it) that potential energies associated with that force exist.

Now root(infinity) is also infinity, if we choose root(infinity)=r, so that r^2= infinity, so for the gravitational potential energy of any two objects to be zero, the object has to be at infinity. Only the difference in gravitational potential energies matters between two locations, which depicts the work done on an object.

Like, if at location r=r1, P.E.= -1J, and at r=infinity, P.E.=0J (has to be), then change in PE, or the work done by us in taking that object from one location to the other (i am not saying anything about the accelerations caused) =0-(-1) J=1J

Conveniently, we could choose r=r1 as 0J for our system, then r=infinity has 1J energy, so still the difference in P.E.=1J only.

Just that by implying that at r=infinity all potential energies are 0 between any masses and that the fact that it is consistent with newton's law of gravity, then all potential energies at locations not at infinity are negative.

So, to answer your heading question, "When is a moving test mass unbound from a black hole?", the mass has to be at infinity

NOTE: For the spacetime curvatures of any object, I also have an unclarified doubt whether that also spatially extends infinitely stretching across all space, so sorry for not answering using GR.

You can also research on:

"Does the Black Hole exert gravity outside the event horizon?"

IF you still feel that I am wrong, then please attach references so that I may be able to update my knowledge.

Comment: Hm, black holes do not have an 1/r potential around them... The force law is not GMm/r^2 ...

Comment: I think it is,
" The gravitational field points in the negative r direction, so when we integrate it over r to get potential, we obtain a negative number. 

For distances far enough from the event horizon to use classical physics,

V=−GMmr

Gravitational potential energy is always negative, with V=0 at r=∞ for all M and m.

For finite r, then, gravitational potential energy varies directly with the mass of the black hole."

See this link: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/620011/gravitational-potential-relative-a-black-hole

Comment: Ex falso quodlibet. In this universe, the potential around a black hole is not 1/r. Citing a half incorrect answer does not change this. The question just asks about the exact potential around a simple black hole.

Comment: I know the other answers 2nd part is wrong, but the first part is correct

Comment: Can you please prove that fact that the potential is not 1/r so that I have the correct info

Comment: 1/r is for the case that space is flat. When space is curved, teh potential changes.